# Progress bar colours not updated as per the value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have small requiremnt on progress bar, based on progress percent we need to update the status with respected colors.

I tried with below code but colors not updated propely.
Here is the code,

```
  $(function() {

 // $("#idProgress").click(function(){
        var progressPer = 76;

        //var progressPer = $("#idTxtVal").val();

        $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
                value: progressPer
        });


        if (progressPer < 0 || progressPer > 25) {
            $(".ui-widget-header").css("background","red");
        }else if (progressPer < 26 || progressPer > 75){
            $(".ui-widget-header").css("background","yellow");
       }else if(progressPer < 76 || progressPer >  100){
             $(".ui-widget-header").css("background","green");  
        }

//  });

  });
```

Please share me your ideas

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pph9L1ft/26/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition checks that you made was wrong, do it like below,

```
if (progressPer >= 0 && progressPer <= 25) {
  $(".ui-widget-header").css("background", "red");
} else if (progressPer >= 26 && progressPer <= 75) {
  $(".ui-widget-header").css("background", "yellow");
} else if (progressPer >= 76 && progressPer <= 100) {
  $(".ui-widget-header").css("background", "green");
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pph9L1ft/30/)